# Правильный вывод переменной

Tags: javascript, jquery

Что не так делаю? почему не выводится в консоль переменная Num?

```
<div class="calc>
<select name="action" id="production">
  <option value="180">Значки</option>
  <option value="300">Спортивные медали</option>
</select>
</div>

function calcFind() {
    $('.calc select').change(function() {
        num = $('select#production').val();
    });
}
calcFind();    
console.log(num);
```

Comment: @entithat готово

Comment: @C.Raf.T, не стоит чинить проблемный код из вопроса. Иначе вопрос теряет смысл

Comment: @vp_arth пардон, заработался... )

Comment: У вас глобальная переменная num устанавливается только тогда, когда  произойдёт событие change селекта. Если продублировать строчку с присванием num вне обработчика событий - вы сможете увидеть начальное значение...

Answer (score 2):

Как-то так получается..

У Вас просто `num` было доступно только в функции `calcFind()`, а Вы пытались её передать как параметр из вне, где она не была доступна (её не существовало)

```js
function calcFind() {
  $('.calc select').change(function() {
    var num = $('select#production').val();
    console.log(num);
  });
}
calcFind();
$('.calc select').change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="calc">
  <select name="action" id="production">
  <option value="180">Значки</option>
  <option value="300">Спортивные медали</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: всё такие не так вопрос сформулировал. мне нужно будет из функции переменную num использовать т.к она участвует в формуле калькулятора

Comment: https://codepen.io/st-iv/pen/VQzOXd?editors=1011
попробовал, всё равно ничего не происходит. что же не так?

Comment: @StepanIvanov, честно говоря, я не знаю как лучше Вам сделать ибо не понятно как это будет дальше использоваться.. *(зачем усложнять?)*

Comment: хотя бы в рамках данного вопроса. написал return num, затем вызвал функцию и console.log, почему переменная не выводится? на данный момент это не понятно

Comment: @StepanIvanov, потому, что функция `calcFind()` возвратит только после выбора селекта, а Вы вызываете её ещё не выбрав ничего.

Comment: а как сделать что возвратила именно переменную?

Comment: @StepanIvanov, этот кусочек `var n = calcFind();` надо писать уже после того как выбрали значение из селекта.

Comment: @StepanIvanov, может быть даже такое, что придется писать все в `$('select').change(function() { // тут });`

Comment: если честно ничего не понятно, был бы вам благодарен, если приведёте пример кода

Comment: @StepanIvanov, ну смотрите. Вы вызвали один раз функцию `calcFind()` , а в ней каждый раз когда из селекта выбирают значение будет выводиться `num`(не тот, что нам нужно). По-этому я предлагаю либо делать все вычисления в `$('select').change(function(){ вот тут все делать});`, либо искать более странный вариант. Но учтите, что это может быть затратно к ресурсам..